# let pattern binding, can someone explain with examples?

Tags: types, pattern-matching

I was reading theory and encountered following

```
 let p = t in t   //pattern binding
```

An example with record pattern

```
  let {l1=x1:S1, l2=x2:S2} = E1 in (x1 x2) 

  // l1,l2 are lebels, x1,x2 are variables, S1 and S2 are types.
```

I understand let binding, but not familiar with above form, so I am bit confused. Could anyone give me a real example and explain it? I searched online, but did not see binding with pattern like above.

Comment: what language is this in?

Comment: @JohnColeman. this is written in theory manner, not with a particular language. that is why I need specific example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Swift (and the same seems to be true for Rust, for example) you can use something like this:

```
let (x1, x2) = (0.5, 1) //where x1 would be Double, x2 would be Int based on type inference
```

Here, you bind the values to a matching pair, i.e. first value in the left side in brackets is bound to first value in the right bracket and so forth.

Then, you can use the values of the binding like normal constants, by referencing x1 or x2:

```
print(x1) // prints 0.5
```